# F# - public myClass test;

Tags: f#

I'm fairly need to this whole F# thing and Functional programming.. I've been looking in all possible documents and found nothing, so therefore I ask you for help for my simple problem. How do I declare:

`public myClass test;`

in F#?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469494.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the declaration to go in the module, do

```
let test = myClass()
```

If you want the declaration to go in the class, do

```
val test: myClass
```

You'll have to initialize test in the constructor, or to provide a DefaultValue attribute:

```
[<DefaultValue>]
val mutable test: myClass
```

Then it will be default-initialized to `null`.

The final alternative is to have the private field (then you can initialize it inside the class declaration) and provide an accessor:

```
let test = myClass()
member x.Test = test
```

or

```
let mutable test = myClass()
member x.Test with get () = test and set value = test <- value
```